# How to write if "foo" is not empty do the following unless "bar" is "zee"

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison

I want to check if a row is not empty and send some html to browser but otherwise if session is set and the user owns this row send this piece of html to browser anyway.

I don't want to go to else like this.

```
    <?php if (!empty($row['v'])){?>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>V</strong></td>
  <td style="line-height:13px" class="Edit_True Coll_Info" id="vision"><?php echo     $row['v'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } else if ($check_session == 'yes'){ ?>
<tr>
          <td><strong>V/strong></td>
          <td style="line-height:13px" class="Edit_True Coll_Info" id="v"><?php echo $row['vision'] ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php }?>
```

**I want something like this. Something like "OTHERWISE" or "UNLESS"**

```
<?php if (!empty($row['v']) unless $check_session == 'yes'){?>
//do some stuff here.
```

NOTES:

//This will only work when a user who doesnt own this row is logged in and will not display anything for a user who owns this row.

Comment: __&&__ (meaning __AND__): `if (!empty($row['v']) && $check_session != 'yes'){?>`

Comment: This will not return anything if a user who owns a row is logged in.

Comment: It's what you asked for, if you want a variant, you can use `if (!empty($row['v']) && !($check_session == 'yes')){?` otherwise, make it clear what you're actually asking for

Comment: It's what you asked for. If it's not in your opinion you should rethink your question and make it clear

Comment: What do you mean with "if a user owns this row". How do you define if a user "owns a row"?

Comment: Guys thanks, but really i explicitly indicated the "Unless" and gave an example that i want something that will work as "OTHERWISE" or "UNLESS", not to use && which adds to the !empty($row['v']), instead i want something to override "!empty($row['v'])" when $check_session == 'yes'.

Comment: Now you're making yourself even less clear.... "UNLESS" (in English) means "AND NOT" (when translated to Boolean logic).... PHP (and most computer languages) don't have the keywords "UNLESS" or "OTHERWISE" because they're not needed, because they can always be expressed by combining "AND", "OR" and "NOT"

Comment: It's very much a fundamental of computer programming that you need to be able to express things in logical combinations of AND/OR/NOT... if you can't formulate what you need in these terms in a way that other developers can understand, it's going to be a very difficult career for you

Comment: Someone answered it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
if($checked_session == "Yes" || !empty($row['v']) 
{
  //do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: This is correct, you the first to understand the question, but i don't want to go to "else", i want the if condition to eveluate before else as if its like this: if (!empty($row['v']) else if ($check_session == 'yes')) {do stuff }. The syntax is wrong but something like that.

Comment: @user3109875 if always executes at first only, if `if{}` fails it goes to else.So now i am little bit confused by your comment.

Comment: @user3109875 I think this is what you asked `i want something to override "!empty($row['v'])" when $check_session == 'yes'.`. here if $check_session == 'yes' then it will not check for `empty($row['v'])`. if `$check_session != 'yes'` then only it checks `empty($row['v'])`

Comment: i know its a bit childish what im asking, but i thought there would be another methord to do this without going to else. Assume something like this was possible.   if ($a = '1' unless '$b' = '2'){ do this }. What this would do is to first check if v = 1, even, but then even though v might be 1, as long as $b = 2, $v's rulling will be overhauled.

Comment: @user3109875 please use same variables defined in if condition $v is undefined  and `$ = 2`

Comment: please give me an example.

Comment: @user3109875 what is `$ = 2` mean and v is not in if condition

Comment: @user3109875 you mean to say if `$b is 2` then no need to check for `$a` value. If `$b is not 2` then you want to check `$a is 1`

Comment: @user3109875 you have to goto else. You cannot prevent it for your situation. PHP dont have some thing like `unless` or `otherwise` operator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54500/discussion-between-user3109875-and-krishna).

Comment: @user3109875 you should consider baker's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883180/how-to-write-if-foo-is-not-empty-do-the-following-unless-bar-is-zee/23883652#comment36768611_23883180)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

```
if (!empty($foo) && $bar != $zee)
```

Comment: What happens if a user is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention correct use the a AND statement (&& in php) with the negated term.

```
if (!empty($row['v']) && $check_session != 'yes'){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was;
*I want to check if a row is not empty and send some html to browser but otherwise 
if **session is set** and the **user owns this row** send this piece of html to browser anyway.*

That would imply that for **empty** rows you want to check;

```
    if (empty($row['v']) && ($check_session && $owns_record)) "display stuff"
```

Comment: yes but you using "&&", nothing on that statement is "otherwise" or "unless".

Comment: "&&" adds to "empty($row['v'])", i want something that will override "empty($row['v'])" if "$check_session == 'yes'". I don't know how to make this question more clearer.

Comment: If you need to test something __before__ testing empty row, then `if($owns_record) { ... } elseif (empty($row['v']) { ... }`